# How to reset the image in UIImageView without loading the whole view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview

I have a xib which has 1 UIImageView and 1 Toolbar. 
Toolbar has two buttons save and reset.
In the simulator i can make some drawing on the image in the UIImageView. 
  Now i want that if i click on the reset button then i would get the original image if i didn't save the changes on the image. 
 I don't want to load the entire view again. 
 Only I need to replace my edited image with original image? 
 Can you please guide me that how can i do this stuff?

Comment: What do you mean by "load the entire view again"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"];

[imageView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: This will work, but the call to `setNeedsDisplay` isn't needed.  `UIImageView` updates itself when it is assigned a new image.

Comment: No it doesn't, and this method is very slow as it needs to wait for the next drawcycle.

Answer (score 3):

```
UIImageView *imageView;
imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"one.png"];
```

refresh with orignal image. Have u tried this

```
[imageView reloadInputViews];
```

If it not work try this code again to refresh

```
imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"one.png"];
```

Comment: which one works `[imageView reloadInputViews];`
 or **resign code**

Answer (score 0):

Create an IBOutlet using

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *myImageView;
```

Hook this up with your xib file in interface builder and change the image with

```
myImageView.image=originalImage;
[myImageView setNeedsDisplay];
```

You can use `myImageView` to refer to that image view in IB.

Comment: m getting this error after i added code like your  ` Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString scale]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10cb04'
 `

Comment: Thanks. Your code is working fine. There was some other problem with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just set the image property of the UIImageView to the original image.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView new];
[imageView setImage:origingalImage];
```

Comment: I have tried this. But i didn't work. I want to change the image in UIImageView of my nib file. Here you are creating a new UIImageView.

Comment: myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"origionalImageName.png"];

that's it